# Datatables plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Is there any tutorial of how to use [DataTables plugin](http://www.datatables.net) with asp.net mvc(especially server side code)? Thanks

Comment: Did you try my demo project?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833074/datatables-plugin/1834614#1834614  It does exactly what you are asking for.  Seeing the implementation should answer your questions.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/JQuery-DataTables-MVC.aspx You have description and demo code.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few examples that might help you. the first two are examples but the last one is a list  with asp.net mvc and jquery tutorials.

1. [full example of using MvcContrib grid with jQuery datatable](http://blogs.msdn.com/paulwhit/archive/2009/03/28/walkthrough-full-example-of-using-mvccontrib-grid-with-jquery-datatable.aspx)
2. [aspnetmvc tutorials](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnetmvctodolist.aspx)
3. [Tutorials with asp.net mvc and jquery.](http://www.ajaxline.com/25-plus-best-asp-net-mvc-tutorials-and-articles)

Answer (score 0):

See [my post on this subject](http://techencoder.com/2009/12/getting-datatables-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc/).  It has a **complete demo project** that should get you started.

Comment: I find this post legit enough, a good post in his link with a free download!

Comment: This link appears to be dead now

Comment: @MatthewSteeples Fixed the link. Thanks for the heads up!